# Android accept only characters between a-z and A-Z

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to implementing simple logic to accept only characters between `a-z` and `A-Z` programmatically

A simple solution is:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/LanguageText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="@string/app_lan" />
```

In Strings.xml :

```
<string name="app_lan">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</string>
```

But I want to implement that programmatically

```
username.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
            /* if char is not between a-z and A-Z then return*/
            if ((int) s.toString().charAt(0) < 65 && (int) s.toString().charAt(0) > 90 || (int) s.toString().charAt(0) < 97 && (int) s.toString().charAt(0) > 122) {
                return;
            }else{
                /* Accept character */
            }
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
});
```

Comment: first you need to convert char to ascii value after your logic will implement..

Comment: is there any specific reason why you need to implement it programmatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use InputFilters

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
            if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
                return src;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, ok. let me to after delay some minute i accept that, whats different that with `addTextChangedListener` for implementing this solution?